What is the name of thriller/Adventure/horror movie which include this Scene?
I don't remember name of movie but I still remember one specific scene from the whole movie
A young man ( main actor of the movie ) was running in the jungle.Because some creatures were chasing him, and he also lost his clothes as a result of trying to protect himself from that creatures.
After climbed up a rock he saw a lonely house. At that moment there were no clothes left he was completely nude. He entered the house
there were a women[looks like widow] and a child [girl].
The women quickly got a short gun and checked the naked man. The women gave  pants to him but pants are loose.[because those pants are his husband's] After she commanded him go to a room, when he went to the room she closed the door.
She commanded get his hands off pants. Suddenly his pants got down and he was naked the women also removed her clothes .After few minutes creatures surround the house.The child warned her mother knocking the room door but she didn't hear to her daughter because she was having sex with the man.
I watched it 2007.The creatures looks like wolves/Dogs[quadruped] 
Thriller, Adventure movie.  The movie was in English, in color, and was made 2007 or earlier

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title
